# jquery event (on submit) is affecting all my divs and not the only one where the button was clicked?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

what's up guys? look... I have a comment system for my web page... and I've been dealing with this little problem for a entire week. I really need some help here x_x ... the thing is that when a user leave a comment on my page, this comment is showed automatically thanks to ajax, that's ok...

each comment can be voted. and here's my problem... these divs that contain the forms for voting are build dynamically and the thing is that when I do click on the button for sending the form in any comment... the resulting data appears in all the comments! instead of appear in the specific one where the submit button was clicked, so I don't know what to do at this point, I hope you can give me a hand. this is my code

the form:

```
<label > Vote </label>
<form action="vote.php" method="POST" class="form-vote" id="form-vote">
<button class="icon-thumbs-up" id="icon-thumbs-up"></button>
<input hidden="hidden" type="text" name="num-comment" id="num-comment" value="'.$d['id'].'" >
<input  hidden="hidden" type="text" name="point" id="point" value="'.$d['point'].'" >
<p id="actual-points" class="actual-points"> '.$d['point'].'</p> 
<div id="result"  class="result"> </div>
</form>
```

the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready function() {

    $('.form-vote')on('submit', function() {

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: $(this).attr('action'),
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function(data) {

                                $('.actual-points').hide();
                                $('.result').html(data).fadeIn('slow');
            }
        })
        return false;
    }); 
})  
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried saving the 'this' object of the original event and using it inside the success function like this:

```
$('.form-vote')on('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var $form = $(this); // Save here

  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: $(this).attr('action'),
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    success: function(data) {
      // use here
      $form.find('.actual-points').hide();
      $form.find('.result').html(data).fadeIn('slow');
    }
  })
  return false;
});
```

Comment: may also want to `..function(e) { e.preventDefault() ... }`

Comment: @ThrowsException Added it in

Comment: I tried with these changes but it sends me to the php file, it seems the ajax didn't work or the prevent method but the form doesn't stop the submit

Comment: hoooly *** you were so right.. I just add a little change trying to solve it, it's rare but I changed the submit way.. I've added this $('.form-vote').submit(function(e) { instead of this  $('.form-vote')on('submit', function(e) { and it worked! thanks guys for working this out, best answer for you

Answer (score 0):

change this:

```
$('.result').html(data).fadeIn('slow');
```

to this:

```
$(this).find('.result').html(data).fadeIn('slow');
```